# Redireccionar puerto mediante dns

Tags: linux, dns

Hola acabo de comprarme un OpenVZ muy barato, resulta que este vps la ip es compartida entre los usuarios, cada usuario tiene un rango de puerto disponible

Lo que quiero saber si es posible redirigir el puerto 80 del dominio al puerto que tengo abierto con apache

Por ejemplo

> midominio.com:80   ip.publica.del.host:5712

Solo eso quisiera saber

Comment: Los DNS no toman el puerto así que apuntar desde tu dominio a la IP del host no funcionaría como dices, ¿ye le preguntaste a tu proveedor que es lo que recomienda?

Answer (score 2):

La respuesta rápida es que NO. Pero hay varias soluciones alternativas que podrían ayudarte a paliar el problema.

El problema radica en que los navegadores ni tan siquiera tienen soporte para interpretar los [registros DNS llamados `SRV`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV_record) que podrían dar solución directa a tu problema.

Su uso, hipotéticamente, sería el siguiente:

```
# _servicio._proto.nombre.  TTL   clase SRV prio peso puerto destino.
_http._tcp.midominio.com.   86400 IN    SRV 10   10   5712   dns.publica.del.host.
```

Como digo, el problema es que no existe soporte en los navegadores para esa extensión que ofrece el servicio DNS, por lo que generalmente se usan otras soluciones.

Una de ellas podría usar uno de los numerosos servicios de redirección gratuitos (o con publicidad o cuotas muy reducidas) que permiten integrar en un marco HTML (`<frameset>/<frame>`) una URL (que podría ser `http://ip.publica.del.host:5712`), una redirección HTTP (cabecera `Location`) u otros sistemas similares.

Ejemplos:

- TinyURL: URLs cortas pero difíciles de recordar (http://tinyurl.com)
- Webalias: URLs amigables con dominios preexistentes (http://webalias.com/)
- DotTK: dominios propios gratuitos .TK/.ML/.GA/.CF/.GQ con soporte para redirección (http://www.tk/)
- Registradores DNS con soporte para redirección web: permiten registrar el dominio y en vez de alojar ellos la página redirigir a la URL que se le configure.

También existen servicios de CDN (pero generalmente suelen ser de pago, los gratuitos no suelen soportarlo) que permiten configurar el motor (backend) con puertos no estándar, al igual que también tienes la posilibidad de usar un reverse proxy en otro servidor dedicado que tengas.